# getting error 503 with django on litespeed

Tags: django, python-3.x, litespeed

I created a django project on litespeed and did 
    collectstatic and
    migrate .
but when i requeset, it return 503 error.
this is .hataccess file:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/hyperele/shop"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/hyperele/virtualenv/shop/3.7/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
```

and this is settings.py file:

```
.
.
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.hyperelectrode.ir','hyperelectrode.ir']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'shop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+'/tmp'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'shop.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR+'/public'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

there is no cgi-bin directory in my public_html folder. is it my problem. if yes ,what should i do??

I'm using django==2.0 and python3.7.

Comment: May I ask this is the wiki that you followed but not work? and is this OpenLiteSpeed? could you also provide the context settings? Did public folder filled with your static files after doing the collect?  https://openlitespeed.org/kb/python-wsgi-applications/#Django_Setup

Comment: It's not a VPS,  it's a host and i can't access it as root. I didn't do anythings about web server. and collectstatic did without any problem.